# ActionMode menu not hiding menu item

Tags: android, menuitem, android-appcompat, android-menu, android-actionmode

I'm using an action mode with my list view for multi-select. The problem I'm having is that the icon I've specified as hidden in my action mode's menu is never hidden in an overflow menu when testing on emulator, although in the preview it is. I'm using AppCompat theme here is my menu.xml --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tag"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Tag"
        android:icon="@drawable/in_ic_tag_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/label_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/in_ic_delete_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

When using Action Mode, the `app:showAsAction="never"` doesn't work:

change:     `app:showAsAction="never"`

to:         `android:showAsAction="never"`

---

Or use this line of code:

`menu.findItem(R.id.XXX).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);`

Comment: Specifically, this is needed when using `android.view.ActionMode`, but not `androix.appcompat.view.ActionMode`. You can use `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"` to suppress the warnings when using `android:showAsAction`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you try to hide your MenuItem with showAsAction. "Never" means in this case that it will just not shown as a icon, but it is in the overflow menu.

Maybe you are looking for visibility. For example:

```
android:visible="false"
```

Documentation for the programmatically approach: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)

Comment: Nope I don't wan't it to be invisible. I'm trying to put it inside the overflow menu which generally works by specifying `showAsAction = never` in all other parts of my app except for action mode.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer then.

Comment: thanks for the help mate I found the problem I was using the wrong namespace, using `android:showAsAction="never"` solves the problem. Maybe because the ActionMode is invoked by the list view and thus is not the one from `support.v7` library.

Comment: Great to hear! Funny that I answered yesterday to a question with a similar issue, but didn't find this issue here, lol

Comment: @trpride Android Studio marks it as error when using appcompat v22, should I just ignore it and go on?